# How do I add a phone number to my Google Search result?

Tags: google-search, search-results

How can I add a call button on my search result on Google?

[image: Google Search result, displaying a telephone number]

Comment: Do you have your name, address, and phone number marked-up using schema.org somewhere on your site?? The bit you circled comes from the knowledge graph in Google which uses mark-up on sites to gather the information. Cheers!!

Comment: Show the full image, as this could be an ad, so far I've not noticed this for organic results. Share the exact full screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend marking the page up with local schema. [This article is pretty good](https://whitespark.ca/blog/the-json-ld-markup-guide-to-local-business-schema/). I would recommend doing it in JSON-LD.

Answer (score 1):

Create an account at https://www.google.com/business/

Google business allows you to create a business profile with phone, address, etc.